# EJB named query preference

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, ejb

I have a database with this structure.

[image]

I am using JSP + Servlet + Entity Classes from database + Session Beans for entity classes. As you can see, my tables are normalized which in return makes it necessary to join tables to obtain the whole details of a patient/staff. As i studied the https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/intro.html i saw that they access the database by using the facade.find etc and etc. Considering my case, I have also tried using the same thing.

For example. I have a session bean (Profile Manager) which accesses the entities and puts it in the map.

```
public Map getPatientDetails(int patientID)
{
    Map patientMap = new HashMap();

    Patient patient = patientFacade.find(patientID);

    User user = userFacade.find(patient.getUserId().getId());
    UserContact userContact = user.getUserContact();
    Family family = familyFacade.find(patient.getFamilyId().getId()); 
    String patientDOB = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM dd, yyyy").format(user.getDateOfBirth());

    patientMap.put("familyRecord", family);
    patientMap.put("patientRecord", patient);
    patientMap.put("patientDOB", patientDOB);
    patientMap.put("userRecord", user);
    patientMap.put("userContactRecord", userContact);

    return patientMap;
}
```

As I give myself time to think about it, I thought that I can join the entities by using and setting a namedquery instead making it a single access. Which is the right way to do this? Do you think using facades to access my database is better than constructing an inner join query to acheive getting all the information at once? What would you guys suggest? Thanks!

Comment: Usually DataAccess class names are suffixed with `DAO` or `Repository` like PatientDAO or PatientRepository and not `Facade`. It might not be intuitive.

Comment: @Javakid Additional Question: My Session bean's name is Profile Manager because it handles all registration of the staff and patient as well as mapping them to a map. Do you think I should seperate it to PatientDAO and StaffDAO?

Comment: I think you mean `PatientProfileManager` and `StaffProfileManager` and not `DAO`. It actually depends on how different the profile creation logic between Patient and Staff. I would start with single ProfileManager. I follow TDD methodology and based on how complex my unit testing is growing, I refactor it into separate Manager classes. But if I know the logic is radically different upfront, I would create two Manager classes (separation of concern law).

Comment: `DAO` means Data Access Object which contains code to fetch data from database. Service, Facade, and Manager names are used in service layer where your business logic resides and it is the place where you do mapping.

Comment: @Javakid Thanks! As a student, I have learned and understood the logic of constructing manager classes!

Comment: If you are satisfied with my answer, please accept it as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to avoid joins in your SQL as, in my experience, it is one of the main root cause of performance issues associated to data access layer.

I would suggest to fetch entity one by one (like hibernate). In this method, there will be round trips to the database. But the SQLs will be simple and thus faster.

Comment: Are you saying that I should continue doing what I did with getPatientDetails() ?

Comment: Yes. The problem with join is the tables might be large and joining large tables or multiple tables causes heavy CPU usage issue. In one of my project which I fine tuned had a lot of joins on large tables and I refactored to access entity by entity.